# ArcGIS Explorer Map Display Issue

Tags: arcgis-explorer

I bet this is probably an issue with my PC, but I have a really odd error with ArcGIS lately.

Refer to the image, it'll explain it best:

[image: ArcGIS Explorer Issue]

Notice how their no map displayed? No matter what I do I can't get it to display. If I add data, change the basemap, restart my computer, re-installed Explorer. This started happening about a week ago for no apparent reason. Nothing had crashed or changed recently on my PC.

Has anyone ever heard of any bugs that might be the cause of this?

My ArcGIS Explorer build is: 1750 (2.0.0.1750)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a Windows XP PC - http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-explorer/1750/system-requirements click the link to 'Check your computer's ability to run ArcGIS Explorer Desktop' http://cyri.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri_if/1186/10913

Comment: I hope it can run ArcGIS Explorer as it already was before. I still ran the 'Can You Run It?' and it did come up with a warning about my video card. I'll have to look into this.

Comment: video cards like any equipment can start to fail... or think about getting something newer... before it is too late.

Comment: Easier said than done! This is an old server computer with XP installed, works decent, but not great. Half of my job is spent troubleshooting it! Thanks for the input. I find it very odd this computer can run ArcGIS for Desktop no problem, but runs into problems at explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was a driver issue. The graphics card I am running has an issue with its Pixel Shader version. A quick update to my graphics card driver solved it. Thanks for all the input.