# Running ArcGIS Desktop in virtual machine?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, linux, windows-7, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 in a Windows 7 (32bit) virtual machine. I don't have any native Microsoft Windows available. I'm using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) from Oracle for virtualization in a native linux environment (Sabayon).

I'm having exactly this issue: [ArcGIS Explorer Map Display Issue](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/37291/13692)

The proposed solution is to update video card driver. But in VirtualBox there are driver called "Guest additions" and they are already up-to-date.

I know some of my fellow students are working with ArcGIS in VMs and they seem not to have any kind of issues. What could it be?

[image: the map only renders on right-click]

3D- and 2D-Video-acceleration are enabled.

---

- It's a native Linux machine, running a virtual Windows 7 machine - 32bit.
- I'm aware of ESRI's system requirements. I allocated 256MB video RAM and enabled 2D and 3D hardware acceleration - as seen in the screenshot. Anyways, I've been running [this](http://cyri.systemrequirementslab.com/1186/10913) analyzation of my system requirements from inside the machine, this is the result:

[image: system requirements test results]

Now I got to figure out how to fix it. Video memory is okay, but the rest I've never heard of...

---

I installed the [experiemental WDDM drivers](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d) as @scw suggested, now it looks like that:

[image: system requirements test results]

I have all recommended attributes now, but it still says:

> Unfortunately, your Video Card does not meet this requirement.

In addition, ArcGIS crashs now after adding any layers.

Comment: you have a linux tag - where does that tie in with Oracle Virtual Box running Windows 7?

Comment: is your Windows 7 (32 bit or 64bit?)

Comment: @Mapperz, I'm guessing that donschoe is running a native linux box, and has created a Windows 7 VM that is running inside Oracle VirtualBox.

Comment: Updated my question: the VM is Win7-32bit and yes, I'm running it inside a native Linux box.

Comment: @donschoe Hardware T&L,  is the ability of a graphics processor to do transform and lighting calculations. The other two are software (I think) components that are involved in Graphics display. Looks like ArcGIS requires these and your Virtual Machine does not support them. Have you tried creating a virtual machine on Vmware Player? I have used virtual machines with VmPlayer with reasonable performances.

Comment: How did you install 3D support? You should try both the WDDM and the experimental Direct3D versions to see if either one works as expected. You'll need to install the driver in safe mode, and make sure you meet the requirements described in the Virtualbox manual: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d

Comment: i wasn't aware of the difference between wddm and basic 3d drivers, anyways, installing wddm only made things worse, see second update.

Comment: I see, it looks like the VirtualBox 3D support is insufficient in some way. I'd recommend disabling hardware acceleration in ArcGIS, which should force it to rely on 2D primitives: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/02/05/display-options-for-hardware-acceleration-and-remote-desktop/  Alternatively, you could try connecting to the machine via RDP, but this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: currently i can't do anything after starting arcmap except shutting down the machine. i'm totally fed up with this kind of software and i'm not going spend any more time and nerves on this topic. i can't understand why universities spend money on licenses for arcgis while there are so many free alternatives. thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: disabling hardware acceleration fixed it :facepalm:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve the rendering-issues in VirtualBox you need to disable 3D-Hardware- and 2D-Video-Acceleration.

This is quite paradox, but I asked friends who used ArcGIS in a VirtualBox session and they simply told me I should try to turn off the acceleration.

It works.

Comment: qdoe: I have a machine running Ubuntu 11.04 and am very interested in trying ArcGIS through VirtualBox. Before I install VirtualBox, I am wondering if you could give me an update on how this configuration is working out for you. I have successfully run QGIS on this computer, as well as GDAL and GRASS, but I want to be able to run ArcGIS as well. Thanks

Comment: Just install VirtualBox and set up a Windows 7 virtual machine. Start it, go to Devices > Insert Guest Additions > Install them without 3D support. In VM settings disable 3D- and 2D-acceleration. This works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

disabled 3d Hardware and 2d Video worked for me, Arcgis 10 running on Windows 7 64 bits in a native Linux Ubuntu Machine

Answer (score 3):

ArcGIS Desktop does not require a high end graphics card. It can run with a low end Graphics card or even without one. What it requires is  hardware graphics acceleration to draw all the gradients and shading as well as dynamic display.

Have a look at the [hardware requirements](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.1/index.html#/ArcGIS_10_1_for_Desktop/015100000002000000/) of Arcgis Desktop?

> 64 MB RAM minimum, 256 MB RAM or higher recommended. NVIDIA, ATI, and
>   Intel chipsets supported.
>
> It requires atleast 24-bit capable graphics accelerator
>
> OpenGL version 2.0 runtime minimum is required, and Shader Model 3.0
>   or higher is recommended.
>
> Be sure to use the latest available driver.

There is a big chance that your virtual machine might not meet the requirements, but  try running http://cyri.systemrequirementslab.com/1186/10913 to see if your virtual Machine is supported.

The 3D Acceleration Support in VirtualBox is quite limited, according to [this thread](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=16).

Comment: +1 for answer, and system requirements. But i don't understand this part of your answer `or even without one` can you explain can I realy launch arcgis without graphic card? From my expierance: when I tried to install arcgis desktop on virtualbox it worked realy slow. However arcgis server works good.

Comment: My main development machine does not have a separate graphics card. my display is run off the (motherboard's) onboard display driver. And ArcMap runs fine on it. What I meant was that ArcMap does not require a heavy duty graphics card. It can run fine, as long as Hardware acceleration in enabled (which onboard graphics can do). Virtual box does not have hardware acceleration, and hence arcmap has terrible performance. As an aside, VmPlayer does have 3d acceleration emulation, and I have seen reasonable performance of ArcGIS desktop (even arcGlobe) on it.