# Opening multiple instances of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro

Is there a way to run concurrent ArcGIS Pro instances under the same window account?

It appears that ArcGIS Pro 1.x doesn't allow this with the default configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArcGIS Pro 2.0 has just been released yesterday.

I tried it briefly this morning and found that **it will in fact allow multiple instances to be opened**.

So while it was not possible to open multiple instances with ArcGIS Pro 1.x, it is possible to do so using 2.x.

Here is a screenshot of my laptop with 4 ArcGIS Pro instances running

[image]

See [What's new in ArcGIS Pro 2.0](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/whats-new-in-arcgis-pro.htm)

> - You can now open and run multiple instances of ArcGIS Pro at the same time. Work on multiple projects simultaneously and open a new or
>     existing project without closing your current project.
> - The same project can be opened several times. The first time a project is opened, ArcGIS Pro will have a writable copy of the
>     project. All other instances of the project will be read-only. You can
>     work with a read-only project in the same manner as if the project is
>     writable; however, on saving your changes you will see the Save
>     Project As dialog box. Save a copy of the current project file (.aprx)
>     to a writable location if you want to keep your changes. Learn more
>     about opening and saving projects.

You should be able to auto-update from 1.x to 2.0 from within the ArcGIS Pro application.  If it doesn't give a pop-up saying a new version is available, you can go to the Application menu > About and check for updates.

Answer (score 9):

At this time, no, you cannot open multiple instances of Pro on the same machine.
You can open Pro on different machines (up to 3) with the same named user as long as the license has not been taken offline.

Idea: [Two ArcGIS Pro Maps Open at the Same Time](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000005HKvIAM)

Comment: I discovered that this constraint is machine-wide.  If another user has started ArcGIS Pro, any other user will get the same error message (before the AGOL login window).

Comment: you can with a virtualbox/vm http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48957/how-to-run-arcgis-in-a-virtual-machine

Comment: Jim McKinney mentioned at the DC #devsummit something about making this possible once they implement multi-threaded display cache (or something like that). It's on its way but he didn't give a specific version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with version 2.0.1.  The amount of memory consumed by Pro is now reasonable, it is similar to opening an instance of ArcMap.  Previously, it was almost double.  If you have large datasets or imagery, this may still be a problem.  Consider setting the view scale for those datasets when zoomed out beyond a certain scale.