# Can McAfee break ArcGIS Toolboxes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arctoolbox

I have ArcMap 10.3 installed on a server.  Everything was going great until recently all the toolboxes stopped working.  They would load but be blank.  I googled this and found McAfee AntiVirus software can cause this issue.

I tried using both the McAfee instructions and Esri instructions for fixing this issue.  I should clarify (I sent the instructions to IT and they tried, I do not have the permissions to perform these fixes, so I cant for sure know how they did it.)  This did not help.  So ArcMap was uninstalled and re-installed on a special server that has no McAfee software.  This server is much slower and ArcMap crashes with the smallest tasks, ect adding a field to a table.  It is technically against corporate policy to not have McAfee running on a workspace, and so this solution is only temporary anyway.

Has anyone else run into this issue, and what was your solution?

Comment: My paths to data are very long.  Can this cause performance issues?

Comment: You can run ArcGIS in a virtual machine/box that does not have an anti-virus - example https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/create-virtual-machine

Comment: related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48957/running-arcgis-desktop-in-virtual-machine

Comment: I like the vm idea, I should mention it was on a vm on the server, but I may be able to convince IT to create a vm without McAfee

Comment: you can run it on your local pc (most likely you will need local admin rights)(it is contained so not to worry about viruses)